# Upgrading jenkins in production environment

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cloudbees

can some one explain some steps how to upgrade Jenkins manually in production where server doesn't have any internet. what precautions do we need to take for production env before upgrading. How to manage plugins upgrade too if there is no internet

thanks....

Answer (score 3):

So there are multiple options. Blue-Green, Regular Upgrade, Advance Test Upgrade

1. Blue-Green - Spin up another instance of Jenkins for the desired version. Copy plugins, jobs directories from PROD to new Instance of Jenkins. Verify the setup is working as expected. Apply any patches specific to version if required. E.G: Upgrade incompatible plugins specific to new Jenkins version. Test all types of Jobs. Finally Make the newly installed instance as PROD and make the existing as passive. You can repeat the same exercise in future and the passive becomes active in future. Infact you can put a Apache Reverse proxy infront of both instances, and make your Apache point to the desired instance for PROD.
2. Regular Upgrade - Inform all required and impacted parties. Take an approval for the downtime. Take the backup of you JENKINS_HOME. Make a note of Plugins that are incompatible in newer version of Jenkins. Upgrade to new version.  Replace the incompatible plugins with supported version and finally test the jobs. Worst case if you are running out of time rollback to backup version.
3. Advance Test Upgrade - Copy the Jenkins_HOME. Install Jenkins new version on some other machine. Copy the jobs,workspace, plugins and config.xml. Verify the new instance is working. Make a note of things that you followed for the upgrade. Next take an approval for Downtime of PROD jenkins. Upgrade Jenkins based on the above steps.

Please comment if you need additional details specific to any of the above 3 options

Comment: Thank you @Jeel. I appreciate your help.  we installed Jenkins using RPM package for production, What will be the procedure for upgrading Jenkins which is installed using RPM